# How to use latest OpenSSL for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, openssl

My server OS is CentOS release 6.6 
It has OpenSSL version 1.0.1e-fips

## /usr/bin/openssl version

OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

I want to install latest OpenSSL in different location and use it for Nginx.

## /usr/local/bin/openssl version

OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

Also want to verify which OpenSSL the currently running Nginx is using.

Comment: following url it may help to you https://gist.github.com/MattWilcox/402e2e8aa2e1c132ee24

Comment: Centos backports the latest fixes into its rpms. That is, the latest centos version is equivalent to the official version.